# Find the degree of the extension $\Bbb R(\theta)/\Bbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I'm doing an exercise in Stewart and Tall's Algebraic Number Theory which has me confused.

> Suppose $\theta$ satisfies $p(\theta) = \theta^3 - 7\theta + 6 = 0$, but that
>   $\theta \notin \Bbb R$. Find the degree of the field extension $\Bbb R(\theta)/\Bbb R$.

What is meant by $\theta \notin \Bbb R?$ The polynomial $p(x)$ splits entirely over $\Bbb R$ as $(x + 3)(x-2)(x-1)$ so that, considered over $\Bbb R$, the extension is trivial.. how should I think about $\theta$ when all of the roots of $p$ lie in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Well, it won't be a field, but you can just look at the ring of rational functions in the variable $\theta$ with the property that $\theta^3$ may be exchanged for $7\theta-6$. At least I think that's what they mean.

Comment: @Arthur The exercise suggests that the result be a field, perhaps it's just a typo?

Comment: @Cauchy Where the parentheses refer to the ideal generated by $x-1$?

Comment: @Cauchy I'm fairly certain that $\Bbb R[x]/(x-1) \cong \Bbb R$ anyway

Comment: @Cauchy It seems a little stupid anyway. There are no intermediate extensions between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ so if $\theta \notin \Bbb R$ then $\theta \in \Bbb C$, so the degree should just be $2$?

Comment: @Cauchy I don't know, seems like there's nowhere else for it to go unless we can consider polynomials as well as you suggested.

Comment: In my example, the only way to make sense of $\mathbb R(\theta)$ is to consider $\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb R[x]/(x-1)$, which makes the extension of degree $1$, again. Yeah that's stupid. Deleting comments...

Answer (score 3):

This surely must be some typo: as you say, no such $\theta$ exists, since every root of $p(x)$ is real.  I'm guessing the problem statement meant to have a slightly different cubic which has non-real roots, in which case the conclusion would be that $\mathbb{R}(\theta)$ is $\mathbb{C}$.